# Why schedule and requests library don't work with this Class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, schedule, python-class

I'm a very beginner. I have this Class where I want to get some data from a website once every day (here every seconds because I was testing it) at a certain hour. I want to use schedule module and I can't figure what is the problem. I use Pycharm and the programs just runs with no output.

```
import requests
import time
import schedule

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://www.website.com'
        self.params = {
        ...
        }
        self.headers = {
        ...
        }

        self.orders = []

    def fetchCurrenciesData(self):
        r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
        return r['data']


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(Bot)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I also tried to do this:

```
impactBot = Bot()

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(impactBot())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But here I get an error where they say "Bot object is not callable". What do I do wrong?

Comment: You're only ever calling the class constructor. You're never calling the method that actually makes the request.

Comment: OK, I can call it with "schedule...do.(impactBot.fetchCurrenciesData)" as the other user suggested, but still the programs runs with no output

Comment: If you want to show output why you don't put print stement in method `fetchCurrenciesData`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call class for init object and then call method of object class.
for resolve it follow my example:

```
ClassObj = Bot()
# Call method fetchCurrenciesData
ClassObj.fetchCurrenciesData()

# or 
# Singal line
Bot().fetchCurrenciesData()
```

Below is the example of your code.

```
import requests
import time
import schedule

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://www.website.com'
        self.params = {
        ...
        }
        self.headers = {
        ...
        }

        self.orders = []

    def fetchCurrenciesData(self):
        r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
        return r['data']


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(Bot().fetchCurrenciesData())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Great, I have the same problem, spent hours googling the solution, thanks you saved my day :)

Comment: Thank you, but I stil get the "TypeError: the first argument must be callable" Error after I did what you wrote

Comment: In Pycharm I also get this error from the schedule package file if it helps: /.../site-packages/schedule/__init__.py, line 440, in do self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `Bot().fetchCurrenciesData()` will only be executed once, and the _result_ (which can't be callable) will be handed to `.do`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
impactBot = Bot()

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(impactBot.fetchCurrenciesData)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

`schedule....do()` needs a callable.

Comment: Done, but the programs still continues running with no output

Comment: @User147 Why do you expect output? I don't see any calls to `print` that would produce some output. Do you just want to "see" `r["data"]` every 5 seconds? Then put `print(r["data"])` inside the `fetchCurrenciesData` method (instead of returning it)